# Alternatives to the coins supplied in Puerto Rico

Tags: puerto-rico, components, custom-game-pieces

After getting the Rio Grande Treasure Chest for the two Puerto Rico expansions, I want to spice up my set of Puerto Rico a little bit.

Can anyone recommend any good sites where I could get physical coins to use instead of the $1 and $5 pieces in the game?  I was thinking period-authentic replicas, or just even nice looking small gold and silver doubloon-looking coins.

Comment: According to the actual fact, this question wouldn't fall under the shopping question type?

Answer (score 13):

[Board Game Bits](http://www.boardgamebits.com/store/) has little wooden disks in various sizes.  You could get some cheap plastic pirate coins you can get at pirate stores.  This might help spice things up also.  There is also a company out of Australia, [Campaign Coins](http://www.campaigncoins.com.au/), that specializes in coinage useful for games and LARPs.  They're prices are a little steep at $7 for ten coins, but they have a good selection of different designs.

Comment: Both this links are broken. Can you update the links?

Answer (score 4):

I got real gold doubloons from The Great American Coin Co. They are about the size of a nickel, and are authentic looking, real metal coins based on the 17th century Spanish doubloon. They make the game so much more fun!

http://www.greatamericancoincompany.com/c5/Shiny-Gold-Doubloon-Replicas-You-Choose-Quantity-p184.html

Comment: Christopher, welcome to B&CG.  Thanks for sharing your experiences here!

Answer (score 3):

I got some really nice doubloon coins from [Momcorp](http://momcorp.com/moms-famous-antique-doubloons/).  They're a lot more enjoyable than the paper coins, and a pretty good deal for $29 -- you get 50 coins (40 small silver coins & 10 large gold coins).

http://momcorp.com/moms-famous-antique-doubloons/